# I can't display images from database MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, display

I can't display images from database.
I have folder called `images` next to `index.php` where I keep images.

I suppose I have wrongly defined folder path with images or sth else.

```
<?php
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "crud");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
    $res = $connection->query($sql);
    if(@$res->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
        {
            ?>
            <img src="<?php "C:/xampp/htdocs/img_mysql/images/".$row['image'] ?>" style="width:170px;height:120px" />
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

[I put picture with how look my website when I try display images.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw9R6.jpg)

Comment: you didn't use the command echo in the php tag, inside the src attribute of img

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer. I will check your solution, but not now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

2 Issues:

1. You are not outputing anything.
2. You are using a path to the file on your computer rather than of the
   server itself.

Fix it like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo "/images/".$row['image'] ?>" style="width:170px;height:120px" />
```

You shouldn't use a domain in your frontend pathes for the simple reason that in production you will have a different domain. If you really want to for some reason, a fine solution will be using a constant, something like this:

[In a file included from all pages]:

```
define("IMAGES_PATH", "http://localhost/images/");
```

Then

```
<img src="<?php echo IMAGES_PATH . $row['image'] ?>" style="width:170px;height:120px" />
```

Comment: I had to add dot to path: "./images/".$row['image']    but thank you very much!!! :) You explain me very well.  EDIT: I cant give you PLUS...

Comment: @makoszet that will be in the case that index.php is not in the root. Anyway, did it work for you eventually?

Comment: Yes, is working. :) why index.php is not a root? I thought that index.php is always the root.

Comment: @makoszet yes, it should. and if that's also the situation in your case, then `/images/...` should have worked just the same as `./images/...`. and since it worked for you you should accept this answer. (it's the tick button)